# JSF Validation of non-selected items

Tags: jsf, primefaces

## Issue

I have a form where a user can enter a delimited string of user names and this is then converted into entries in a `selectOneListbox`.  I have a custom validator which checks the user names but this is only triggered for the highlighted entry.    What I would like to be able to do if validate all the entries in the list whether or not they are selected.   Is this possible?

## Details

The view is simply

```
<p:inputText id="users" value="#{myBean.usersText}" />

<p:commandButton value="->" action="#{myBean.onAddUsers}" update="users,userList" process="users @this" />

<p:selectOneListbox id="userList">
  <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.userList}" />
  <f:validator validatorId="my.package.UserValidator" />
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

and the backing bean has

```
  private String usersText;
  private List<String> userList;

  public void onAddusers() {
    List<String usersToAdd = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(usersText.split(";")));
    for (String u : userToAdd) {
      userList.add(u.trim());
    }
    users = null;
  }
```

Comment: the `inputText` ?   That might contain a delimited list.   The validator is used elsewhere so I don't really want to be changing that to do the splitting and iterating over the values

Comment: The existing validator is going to need a little refactoring which I was trying to avoid (it belongs to someone else) but it is more the validating a list without selection that is a problem.   The only way I can see of doing it is to swap the `selectOneListbox` for a `selectManyMenu` and set the value and selectItems value to the same list in the backing bean.  The validator is then passed a collection which I can iterate over.   Ideally I want to do this without selection as that introduces some UX issues

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ validate the user input

Comment: You are of course right and making use of the Primefaces chips component makes this a lot simpler